# profiling simple python script

Tags: python, performance, cprofile

i was experimenting with `cProfile` for profiling python applications.so i wrote a simple script and below is the results that i have.

```
def foo():
  for i in range(100000):
    print i

def bar():
  for i in range(100):
    print "bar"*i

foo()
bar()
```

When i run the above script as `python -m profile script.py` i get this output:

```
         7 function calls in 0.136 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(range)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 :0(setprofile)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.136    0.136 lip.py:1(<module>)
        1    0.136    0.136    0.136    0.136 lip.py:1(foo)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 lip.py:5(bar)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.136    0.136 profile:0(<code object <module> at 0x7fae5a978a30, file "lip.py", line 1>)
        0    0.000             0.000          profile:0(profiler)
```

but from the ouptut is seems only method `foo` consumed **0.136 s** to excute while it was **0.00 s** for method `bar`. why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing 1000x more work in `foo` than in `bar`.

Assuming they had the same speed, `0.136 / 1000 = 0.000136` which is too small of a number for this display, and `bar()`'s time  just rounds to `0.00`.